# Where in the cockpit of a fighter such as the F-22 or Su-57 is thrust vectoring controlled?

Tags: flight-controls, fighter, thrust-vectoring

Does it use the stick? Pedals?

Comment: A long talk about F-22 controls by a test pilot: https://youtu.be/n068fel-W9I (the gist is that side-stick and pedals tell the computer what the pilot wants and the computer combines all the available control elements to achieve it).

Answer (score 1):

It is controlled by the computer(s). The pilot moves the stick/throttle/rudder in a way to tell the computer(s) what he wishes to do.

The computer(s) move the relevant controls, including the engine nozzles.